# Can native apps on iOS and OS X write and read Safari's website data like cookies and Web Storage?

Tags: ios, macos, cookies, safari, mobile-safari

Can native apps on iOS write and read mobile Safari's website data like cookies and Web Storage?

Can native apps on OS X write and read Safari's website data like cookies and Web Storage?

Thank you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, 
In iOS Safari's cookies are not accessible through iOS SDK apps.And as the reason of sandboxing on the iPhone you don't have access like read/write to Safari's cookies.No Idea with Jailbreak device.

Comment: Thank you. You say native apps can't read cookies in mobile Safari on iOS. Can native apps write cookies to mobile Safari on iOS?